# The new version broom::tidy and speedglm cannot get p values

Tags: r, tidy, broom, speedglm

The following code was from  `help("tidy.speedglm")`. It does not get correct p values. The previous version of `broom` worked fine, but the current version of `broom` (0.7.0) does not work. I wonder if this is a bug or something? Thanks.

```r
library(speedglm)
library(broom)
clotting <- data.frame(
  u = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 100),
  lot1 = c(118, 58, 42, 35, 27, 25, 21, 19, 18)
)

fit <- speedglm(lot1 ~ log(u), data = clotting, family = Gamma(log))
tidy(fit)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    5.50     0.190       28.9      NA
#> 2 log(u)        -0.602    0.0553     -10.9      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It looks like this is the current iterations of `broom` and `speedglm` not working well together, apparently due to the fact of `speedglm` storing p values as characters rather than numeric. Some discussion can be found at https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/pull/881 and https://github.com/MarcoEnea/speedglm/issues/2  Looks like `speedglm` maintainer has agreed to switch to numeric values, so you may want to make sure you have the most up to date version of that (maybe even installing from GitHub)

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks. My package depends on both `broom` and `speedglm`. I will wait for the cran update of `speedglm`.

Answer (score 0):

try `summary(fit)` using broom package